# Cursor themes only work for some applications

Tags: unity, 14.04, themes, cursor, unity-tweak-tool

Trying some X11 cursors from gnome-look.org (Vienna, Protozoa, Leafm, Ecliz... ) in 14.04 Unity. Done update-alternatives and chmod 755.

Everything is ok, cursor themes are visible in unity-tweak, and I can swap between them.

But new cursors work only for some applications, like Firefox and LibreOffice. It seems Unity applications don't accept the new cursor, and dmz-white remains. Curiously, other applications like Software Center mix both cursor themes (new cursor theme for links). Anyway, window bar always force old cursor theme (dmz-white).

Is it possible to only have the new cursor themes?

Comment: I have the same issue

Comment: @JonathanLeaders I had similar issues. Here's how [I solved it](https://askubuntu.com/questions/966997/mouse-pointer-changes-color-in-firefox-and-chrome-and-libre-office-apps/966998#966998)