# Mouse pointer changes color in firefox and chrome and Libre Office apps

Tags: firefox, google-chrome, mouse, themes, libreoffice

I changed my mouse pointer color to the DMZ-Black cursor theme via the command

`sudo update-alternatives --config x-cursor-theme` and at first it appeared that I got the expected results. However, I soon noticed that when I moved the pointer over Firefox, it turned back to what appears to be DMZ-White. Further testing produced the same result in Google Chrome, and all the Libre-office apps. I also noticed it changing from a black pointer to a white hand in Ubuntu Software Center when I pointed at listed applications there.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04.5 with Unity DE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While searching for answers, I stumbled across [this post in the forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2221942&p=13024887#post13024887) which advised to Check what theme is set in dconf. with the command:

`gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme`

I found that even though I had set DMZ-Black in `update-alternatives`, gsettings was still reporting DMZ-White. So I issued the command:

`gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface cursor-theme 'DMZ-Black'` which took effect immediately. No need to logoff and back on like I had to when I applied `update-alternatives`.